# Windows phone tile custom color

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, live-tile, windows-phone-sl-8.1

I'm trying to set custom color to my app's tile. It shows custom color if I pin it start screen. But in the app list, it uses the phone theme color only. How to set the custom color there?

On start screen:

[image: On start screen]

In apps list:

[image: In apps list]

**Note:** This is not a live tile. Tile data is not going to change. I'm developing Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply replace transparency in your images with the color you want.